# How to bridge from Binding<Float> to Binding<String> using an Extension in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, binding, number-formatting

**Context**

I have an `Extension` of `Binding` limited to `Float` which converts it into a `String` for usage with the `SwiftUI` `TextField`. However, I encountered two odd behaviours while not being able to identify the causing issues:

1. When entering more than 4 digits, e.g. 12345, the `TextField` empties
2. When entering a decimal separator (e.g. "." in the US), the `TextField` empties

---

**Code**

```swift
public extension Binding where Value == Float {
    var adapter: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get: {
                guard self.wrappedValue != -1 else { return "" }
                
                let formatter = NumberFormatter()
                formatter.locale = Locale.current
                formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
                
                return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self.wrappedValue)) ?? ""
            },
            set: {
                let formatter = NumberFormatter()
                formatter.locale = Locale.current
                formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
                
                self.wrappedValue = formatter.number(from: $0)?.floatValue ?? -1
            }
        )
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- What causes these errors and how can I achieve my goal of bridging from `Binding<Float>` to `Binding<String>`?

Comment: 1. I suspect that you may be running in to the limit of what a `Float` can hold as it is 32 bit. Try using a `Double` and see what happens. 2. The `NumberFormatter` is probably erroring out as a "," is not a decimal separator in the US, it is the thousands separator. This, of course, is an educated guess because you didn't post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yrb thanks a lot for your answer. However, shouldn’t the NumberFormatter handle these different formats?

Comment: Depends upon what you have the locale set as. Also, `formatter.locale = Locale.current` is redundant. That is already the default, unless you previously set the `formatter` to a different locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, instead use the new formatting style

```
@State private var value: Float = 0

var body: some View {
    //...
    TextField("Value", value: $value, format: .number)
    //...
}
```

Comment: looks great, however, I read that this only changes the state onSubmit, not after every change. Is that correct?

Comment: No it's not. Add an `onChange(of:)` and test it.